# nested for loop in python to do the following

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I am trying to write an equation for a nested for loop. i am getting an error and am trying to understand how to write it?

```
ysub =  GPA
0   0.4509999999999996
1   -0.04900000000000038
2   -0.5490000000000004
3   0.20099999999999962
4   -0.4490000000000003
5   0.19099999999999984
6   0.4509999999999996
7   -0.5490000000000004
8   0.25099999999999945
9   0.05099999999999971
```

Code:

```
i = range (1,10,1)
m = range (1,10,1)
 RMSEtest = ((1/m)*(ysub[i]^2))
```

we have to calculate RMSEtest (sum of values from m = 1 to 10) for each of the ysub values.

Comment: For example, in `1/m` you're trying to divide the integer `1` by the `range` object `range (1,10,1)`, which is not possible.

Comment: okay...thq.so how do we write it? any ideas?

Comment: @satya, what's RMSEtest? If, as your question says, you want to sum all values of `ysub` from m = 1 to 10, then you could do `sum(ysub[k] for k in m)`

Comment: trying to solve an equation (google RMSD). basically i am trying to solve that equation for all the values of ysub

Answer (score 0):

first of all that is not a for-loop. You really don't need to add a third parameter to the `range` because the default is `1`. Your question is unclear about what you need the for-loop to do and the code doesn't help.
For nested for-loops, you want something like:

```py
for x in I:
    for y in m:
        do_something(x, y)
```

Comment: i am trying to solve RMSE (google for equation) for i = 1 to 10 for all the 10 values in ysub.

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of mistakes

1. you cannot divide integer with a range object as told by @ForceBru.
2. You don't need 2 loops for your work
3. To raise the power of an integer or a float, '**' is used instead of '^'

   ```
    ysub = [0.4509999999999996, -0.04900000000000038,-0.5490000000000004,0.20099999999999962,-0.4490000000000003, 0.19099999999999984, 0.4509999999999996, -0.549000000000000, 0.25099999999999945, 0.05099999999999971]
   ```

Code:

```
for m in range (1,10):
    RMSEtest = ((1/m)*(ysub[m]**2))
```

From your code, I think this is what you wanted.